# $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$

Tags: partial-derivative

Consider function $f(x, y)$ smooth enough satisfying the following equation:
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\ .$$
It is obvious, that any function of the form $f(x + y)$ suits the above condition. How can I prove, that these are all functions or find a contradiction?

Comment: Duplicate of [Problems with partial derivatives.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2042778/problems-with-partial-derivatives). Also related to [Geometric interpretation of ${\partial f\over \partial x}= {\partial f \over \partial y}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1038917/geometric-interpretation-of-partial-f-over-partial-x-partial-f-over-pa).

Comment: To be more precise: “Any function $f$ of the form $f(x,y)=g(x+y)$, where $g$ is a (nice enough) function of *one* variable...”